# Swift 3: PDFDocument crashes

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, pdf

I'm trying to write a simple function that will get the number of pages in a PDF. Every code example I've seen now seems to fail with Swift 3, and whatever Xcode recommends still doesn't work.

```
func pageCount(filepath: String) -> Int {

    let localUrl  = filepath as CFString
    let pdfDocumentRef = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, localUrl, CFURLPathStyle.cfurlposixPathStyle, false)
    let page_count = (pdfDocumentRef as! CGPDFDocument).numberOfPages

    return page_count
}
```

And this doesn't work either:

```
func pageCount(filepath: String) -> Int {

    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)
    let pdf = CGPDFDocument(url)
    let page_count = pdf?.numberOfPages

    return page_count!
}
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code as follows:

```
func pageCount(filepath: String) -> Int {
    var count = 0
    let localUrl  = filepath as CFString
    if let pdfURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, localUrl, CFURLPathStyle.cfurlposixPathStyle, false) {
        if let pdf = CGPDFDocument(pdfURL) {
            let page_count = pdf.numberOfPages
            count = pdf.numberOfPages
        }
    }
    return count
}
```

Basically, in your code, you were trying to cast a `CFURL` as a `CGPDFDocument` and you cannot do that :) You need to create a `CGPDFDocument` instance from the `CFURL`. Once you do that, you can get the page count for the PDF document.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Apple has two PDF Objects: `CGPDFDocument`, and `PDFDocument`. The second is much easier to work with.

```
import Quartz

func NumPages(filename: String) -> Int {

     let pdfDoc = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filename))!
    return pdfDoc.pageCount
}
```